# Warning: is_file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given in /var/www/html/lib/internal/Cm/Cache/Backend/File.php on line 508

Tags: magento2, cache

When we add product under women catalog when we want to change the product to offline / change to out of stock; when we try to cancel the order;   not success, and showed the below sentence..  How to solve it ? Please.

> Warning: is_file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string
>   given in /var/www/html/lib/internal/Cm/Cache/Backend/File.php on line
>   508

Comment: magento version ?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by removing the cache

```
rm -rf var/cache var/log var/page_cache var/view_preprocessed
```